# selectionChange property is not firing event in angular class component

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

I was trying to implement angular `MatSelectionList` and tried to listen selected option event using API [selectionChange](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api) , but its not firing any event .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyjdfp?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.html

Am i doing something wrong or anything broke while releasing to angular 6 ?

Using : **Angular 6.0.1 version**

**Chrome Browser**

Comment: are you sure ``selectionChange`` is an angular event ?

Comment: @CruelEngine it is an Angular Material output

Comment: @CruelEngine : https://material.angular.io/components/list/api

Comment: my bad @trichetriche

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The component behavior changed in the [6.0.0-beta.5](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-beta5-2018-03-23) of @angular/material :

> list: selectionChange on the MatListOption, which was deprecated in
>   5.0.0 has been removed. Use selectionChange on the MatSelectionList instead.

You need to apply `selectionChange` on your `mat-selection-list` like this :

```
<mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="onSelection($event)" #shoes>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" >
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

[Here is an edit of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50363834)

Comment: In angular5 , this used to work with mat-list-option element

Comment: You could use `mat-checkbox`, here is an example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50363834-2

Comment: Is it not possible to capture selected value from mat-selection-list options ?

Comment: @AnilKumarArya You can get the selected value using `console.log(event.value);`